# ASP.NET MVC 2 routing: Added language, doesn't work when left away in URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got some routing issues with MVC 2. Might be a simple problem, but I can't make it run. I have registered a second routing including the language:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    // Route name
    "LangRouting",         
    // URL with parameters
    "{currentLang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",         
    // Parameter defaults
    new { currentLang = "de", controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }             
);

routes.MapRoute(
    // Route name
    "Default",
    // URL with parameters
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                 
    // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}             
);
```

Now when I call `{...}/de/Home/Index/` everything works fine. But if I leave the language away and call `{...}/Home/Index/`, the page can't be found ("The resource cannot be found."). I would have expected that this should run without language in the URL and that MVC would insert my default-value in there. How does it work else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use constraint for language.

```
/Home/Index
```

will be translated into first rule as

```
lang = Home
controller = Index
action = Index (from defaults)
```

This should do the trick:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default with language", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
}, new { lang = "de|en" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    lang = "en",
});
```

Comment: Hmmm sounds good, but still doesn't work for me. It still results in a not found, but this time the not found-message arises from IIS: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name 
changed, or is temporarily unavailable." If I keep the language in the URL, it still works as expected.

Comment: Did you keep the second (default) route? Constraint will ensure that the value is there and it is valid, if not it will continue searching for another route. You can't effectively put optional parameter at the beginning of the route by using only one Route instance.

Comment: Now I am not sure if I need to keep the second (default) route? As a matter of fact, I tested it with and without it - unfortunately with the same negative result.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing Answer - it seemed that the application didn't restart altough I recompiled, so the adjustments have had no effect. Now it -- partially -- works. It works for the Home - controller, but not for any other ... :-/  In any other controller, I get the not found-message "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." if the language is missing in the URL.

Comment: I've edited my anwer - this almost exact code I'm using on my project and it works pretty well. Do you have any other routes defined?

Comment: Heh, now it works! I copied again your code from above. No idea what I did wrong before - thank you for your patience. One last question: if I enter a not available language, e.g. fr, it is supposed to end up in a "page-not-found" result, right?

Comment: Yes. It will fail at first route, because FR doesn't match constraint and then it will fail at second route because there is no controller "fr"